# what is the purpose of a gitignore file excluding a preceding dot

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I recently started work on a project with two gitignore files. One of them is the standard: `.gitignore`. and the other is `gitignore` (note the absence of the preceding dot in the file name). Both files have contents.

I created a new file (`foo.fooey`) to see if git 'noticed' the change when running the `git status` command. I then added the `foo.fooey` entry to the regular `.gitignore` and as expected the file was not present when running the `git status` command.

I then removed the entry from the regular `.gitignore` file and put it in the `gitignore` file. As expected, the file was still showing.

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        foo.fooey
```

So what is the purpose of this `gitignore` file? What is more strange is that vscode seems to recognize it, giving it an icon in the shape of a dollar ($) sign.

Forgive me if this question has already been asked somewhere. I googled around and couldn't find it.

Comment: No purpose? A simple typo? Consider doing a `git blame` on the `gitibnore` file. That should tell you who committed it and a commit message. That might shed some more light on why it's there.

Comment: thanks @toniedzwiedz, it was last touched 4 yrs ago and all by the same guy.